# Render Price in external Div

Tags: javascript, html

I have found a code to display the final price based on some selections from a form imputs (checkbox) affecting the final price. I want also it to affect an external div with text on it. Is a huge fixed element I've created displaying "Final Cost" and I also want this to render the final price by changing the `getElementByID` and nothing happened. Could you help me to solve this?

**I want also .priceText1 also to be affected:)**

Actual code is

HTML

```
 <form action="" id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Products
        </legend>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="12.95" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Candy $12.95
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="5.99" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Burger $5.99
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="1.99" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Coke $1.99
        </label>
        <label>
            Total 
            <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
    <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
</form>

<div class="priceWrapper">
            <h3 class="priceText1">$0.00</h3>
            <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>
```

JS

```
function totalIt() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].checked) {
          total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: jQuery: `$('.priceText1').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));` - vanilla JS: `document.getElementsByClassName('priceText1')[0].innerText = '$' + total.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `innerText` with `querySelector` to add the total price to the element `.priceText1` like :

```
document.querySelector(".priceText1").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector(".priceText1").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="theForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Products
    </legend>
    <label>
            <input name="product" value="12.95" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Candy $12.95
        </label>
    <label>
            <input name="product" value="5.99" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Burger $5.99
        </label>
    <label>
            <input name="product" value="1.99" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Coke $1.99
        </label>
    <label>
            Total 
            <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
        </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
  <input value="Reset" type="reset" />
</form>

<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1">$0.00</h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>
```